# Finding an index in a list

Tags: python, indexing, while-loop, row

I have an html file which I open in notepad and read in python as list

```
lst = file.readlines()
```

the html is done like this:

```
<span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold; ">data 27 dic 2022 - 14:25:59::</span><br>
<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color: #0000ff; ">something</span>&nbsp;-&gt; ALTO<br>
<br>
<span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold; ">data 27 dic 2022 - 14:38:38::</span><br>
<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color: #0000ff; ">something</span>&nbsp;-&gt; NO_ACQ<br>
<br>
<span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold; ">data 27 dic 2022 - 14:38:40::</span><br>
```

I'm making a search on word "data" and from there I manipulate the string in order to get the data.
Since I need to iterate this research and I don't want to start everytime from the first "data"/"time"-row, is there a command to get the "index" of the row?

This is the main code:

```
while exit==0:
                  
            timestamp, stop, index=timestamp_search(path,"data",iterazione)
            print ('timestamp=', timestamp)
           

            if timestamp>passed_time and timestamp<actual_time:
                do something
                exit=1
            elif stop==1:
                exit=1
            else:
                iterazione=index+1
```

this instead is  the def:

```
def timestamp_search(file_path, word_1, iterazione):
   
    stop=0
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            lst = file.readlines()
            print ('iterazione',iterazione)
            
            if (lst):
                    if iterazione<len(lst):
                        for index, line in enumerate(lst[iterazione:]):
                            if line.find(word_1) != -1: 
                                print (index,line)
                                #do something to calculate timestamp
                                break
                    else:
                        stop=1
                        return timestamp, stop
            else:
                    print ('File  vuoto')
            
    return timestamp, stop, index
```

I've located the error. Basically it is how I'm passing the information to lst.
I mean:
when iterazione=index=0 in the first cycle, lst starts from index 0 and this is ok
when iterazione=index+1 (in the next cycle) this time lst will start from index 1 and the word "data" will be found at index 3.
Then again in the next cycle iterazione=4 but this time lst will start from index 4 and this means that "data" will be found at index 0 so in the next loop the counter is wrong.

Comment: `for index, line in enumerate(lst)` should do that.

Comment: I've tried the enumerate  in this way: 
lst = file.readlines()
           
            if (lst):
                    print ('iterazione', iterazione)
                    if iterazione<len(lst):
                        for line in lst[iterazione:]:
                          if line.find(word_1) != -1: 
                                print (line)
                                print ('indice_riga',enumerate(line))

but I've got this result:

indice_riga <enumerate object at 0x0000027E1A04C900>

Comment: Please include the code you have tried in the question itself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `enumerate` method to get an additional index attribute while looping.

```
for index, line in enumerate(lst[iterazione:]):
    if line.find("data") != -1: 
        print (index, line)
```

Comment: ahm!I didn't know this was possible! thanks! I'll get a look into it and in case write you again if I still need help

Comment: sorry for disturbing again. 
outside the def where the for is located I've done 
iterazione=index+1

what I see when the def is running is 

0 <span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold; ">data 27 dic 2022 - 14:25:59::</span><b
3 <span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold; ">data 27 dic 2022 - 14:38:38::</span><br>
0 <span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold; ">data 27 dic 2022 - 14:38:38::</span><br>

So the first 2 cycles are ok, but then why it comes back to 0?

Comment: I've added also a print of variable iterazione in order to understand better and it seems that in each cycle it is equal to:
0 --> here it is equal to index
1 --> here index is equal to 3
4 --> here index comes again 0.

Comment: Instead of parsing html manually I suggest you have a look into libraries made for it.

Here's a simple [example](https://pastebin.com/6FxTp2z2) for reading a html file and parsing it using [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/

Comment: ok thanks!The issue I have is that for some reason, even if the variable iterazione is updated to the current index, the lst[iterazione:] is not "cutting" it to the right position

Comment: Where exactly are you updating your `iterazione` variable?
Edit your question and share the full code

Comment: done. I've located the error but I'm struggling to find a good solution